# OS X 10.3.9 Update available?

Tags: software-update, ibook, panther

I just found my old iBook G4, but I only have the installation-cd for OS X 10.3 and I can't find any downloads on the official Apple download pages. Is there some way I still can get the update?

Update: I overlooked the "Load" button
Update2: Actually my iBook is to old to show the Loadbutton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google can always find OS X/macOS updates if you use the keywords 'combo update' followed by the main version - e.g. combo update 10.3

The file is at https://support.apple.com/kb/dl496

A combo update can update anything from 10.x.0 right up to itself, without needing individual updaters for the in-between versions.

Comment: It should be 10.3.x for the combo update.

Comment: As opposed to??? Did you try simply Googling 'combo update 10.3' 10.3.9 is the very first hit; same with any 'combo update 10.n' search, the latest is always first hit.